# How to handle sockettimeoutexception : read timeout while launching a URL via selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium, socket-timeout-exception

I am trying to launch an URL which has an authentication pop up window in chrome browser.
The URL is launched and the pop up is displayed, after this the script fails and the next line of code is not getting executed.

This is my small piece of code

```
public class LogintoCLMReporting {
      @Test
      public void LaunchCLMReportingStage()  {


   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://clm-reporting-prfa.cfcq.isus.emc.com/clm-reporting/");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      System.out.println("Launched");
      driver.quit();
```

This is the error i get.

> FAILED: LaunchCLMReportingStage
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>   Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'

Comment: May you please elaborate what type of authentication is present on the URL and are you passing any values into it ?

Comment: its a sign in pop up which prompts for username and password. with button signin and cancel. Even before i pass any value the script fails.

Answer (score -3):

Kindly use ./ before drivers

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: That doesnt make any difference here.